# Angled div effect?

Tags: html, css

I was browsing though websites to get some inspiration and I came across this one: http://sozodesign.co.uk/

I was wondering how they got the angled div effect? Does anyone know of a tutorial/documentation they can forward to me?

Thanks,

Callum

Comment: http://lawrencenaman.com/css/responsive-slanted-divs-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

Translate and Skew are the two transformation methods which are used in that website to get the desired effect.

> The translate3d() function is used to translate the element by a vector
>   [tx, ty, tz], where tx is the translation along the x-axis, ty is the
>   translation along the y-axis, and tz is the translation along the
>   z-axis. The values tx, ty, and tz are provided either as a  or
>   as a percentage.
>
> The skew() method is used to skew an element along the X and Y-axis by
>   the given angles.

You can have a clear view on these and other transformation techniques at [codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/transform/)